# Entity Framework 6 0.1 to 0.1 relationship with fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

Lets say I want to model a company car pool in Entity Framwork 6:

- I have employees and Cars.
- An empoyee can either have a car or no car.
- A Car can either belong to an employee or no employee.

I know how to model this in a relation database with an intermediate table:

```
EmployeeCarAssociation
-EmployeeId
-CarId
```

With `EmpoyeeId` and `CarId` as primary key and an uniqe constraint on both columns.

But how can I create this 0.1-to-0.1-relation with the EF6 Fluent Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public int? CarId { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Employee)
            .WithOptionalDependent(e => e.Car)
            .Map(config =>
            {
                config.MapKey("EmployeeId");
            });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in Entity Framework, but dosn't enforce the 0.1-0.1 relation on database-level. It only creates a ForeignKey-Constraint in the Car-Table for the EmployeeId. Technicaly, it is still posible to assign multiple Cars to one employee, if one enters the values directly into the Database.
But as long only entity framework is used to alter the data, this is the way to go.